# Comunicação entre diretivas

Tags: javascript, angular

Seguinte galera, tenho uma diretiva no Angular como a do código abaixo:

```
import {Directive, HostBinding, HostListener} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[borders]'
})
export class BordersDirective {

    clicks = 0;

    @HostBinding('style.border') border: string;

    @HostListener('click') click() {
        if (this.clicks === 0) {
            this.border = '2px solid #2d88c7';
            this.clicks++;
        } else {
            this.border = '1px solid #dee2e6';
            this.clicks = 0;
        }
    }

    constructor() {
    }

}
```

em seguida tenho duas tags `p` com a diretiva:

```
<p borders>Elemento 1</p>
<p borders>Elemento 2</p>
```

Quando clico no primeiro elemento ela ativa e então eu clico novamente ela muda a borda, exatamente como era pra acontecer. O problema vem agora, quando eu clico no segundo elemento gostaria que a do primeiro elemento desativasse ou executasse o `else`.

Alguém sabe como resolvo?

Comment: Eu diria que o jeito mais simples é não usar a diretiva, se precisar gerenciar o estado de múltiplos componentes, precisa ser feito em um componente pai, então passe essa lógica para o componente que renderiza os elementos. Mas deve ser possível fazer com diretivas, provavelmente algo como o [`ngSwitch`](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#inside-ngswitch-directives), onde tem uma diretiva pai e outras filhos e, de alguma forma, se comunicam (mas não sei dizer que forma é essa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não é possível fazer a comunicação através de eventos, que seria a forma mais natural:

```html
<div appFather>
  <button appChild>Child 1</button>
  <button appChild>Child 2</button>
</div>
```

O filho emitiria um evento

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appChild]'
})
export class ChildDirective {

  @Output('customClick')
  private customClickEvent = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() { }

  @HostListener('click')
  private click() {
    console.log('child emit');
    this.customClickEvent.emit();
  }

}
```

E o pai iria ouvir esse evento

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appFather]'
})
export class FatherDirective {

  constructor() { }

  @HostListener('customClick')
  private click() {
    console.log('father receives');
  }

}
```

Infelizmente, isso **não funciona**

Mas é possível fazer o que deseja através de um serviço, que controlaria tudo:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class D2DService {

  private static lastClicked;

  private static subject = new Subject();

  constructor() { }

  click(key) {
    D2DService.lastClicked = key;

    D2DService.subject.next();
  }

  isLastClicked(key) {
    return D2DService.lastClicked === key;
  }

  subscribe(listener) {
    D2DService.subject.subscribe(listener);
  }

}
```

É importante que os dados sejam armazenados em uma variável estática porque esse serviço será injetado em múltiplas diretivas, se não cada diretiva terá um serviço que acessa dados diferentes

A diretiva irá utilizar esse serviço pra alterar saber que estado deve ser aplicado ao componente:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appWithService]'
})
export class WithServiceDirective {

  @Input('key')
  private key;

  @HostBinding('style.background-color')
  private backgroundColor = null;

  constructor(private service: D2DService) {
    this.service.subscribe(() => this.backgroundColor = service.isLastClicked(this.key) ? 'yellow' : null);
  }

  @HostListener('click')
  private click() {
    console.log('clicked');
    this.service.click(this.key);
  }

}
```

```html
<button appWithService [key]="'any identifier'">Child 1</button>
<button appWithService [key]="2">Child 2</button>
```

Isso pode ser melhorado, criando as chaves das diretivas automaticamente, adicionando um valor pra servir como container, de forma que diferentes grupos possam ser usados ao mesmo tempo

Há outras formas de se fazer, mas a ideia é centralizar o estado (dados) em um ponto fora da diretiva que deve consultar esse estado pra saber o que deve ser feito

Uma outra forma interessante de se fazer, utilizando apenas diretivas, é criar um diretiva pai que funcione como um serviço

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appFatherWithHost]'
})
export class FatherWithHostDirective {

  private lastClicked;

  private subject = new Subject();

  constructor() { }

  click(key) {
    this.lastClicked = key;

    this.subject.next();
  }

  isLastClicked(key) {
    return this.lastClicked === key
  }

  subscribe(listener) {
    this.subject.subscribe(listener);
  }

}
```

E importar na diretiva filho através da anotação `Host`

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appChildWithHost]'
})
export class ChildWithHostDirective {

  @Input('key')
  private key;

  @HostBinding('style.background-color')
  private backgroundColor = null;

  constructor(
    @Host() private father: FatherWithHostDirective
  ) {
    father.subscribe(() => this.backgroundColor = father.isLastClicked(this.key) ? 'yellow' : null);
  }

  @HostListener('click')
  private click() {
    console.log('child clicked');
    this.father.click(this.key);
  }

}
```

O funcionamento é igual, mas, dessa forma, já separa em grupos isolados:

```html
<div appFatherWithHost>
  <button appChildWithHost [key]="'any identifier'">Child 1.1</button>
  <button appChildWithHost [key]="2">Child 1.2</button>
</div>
<div appFatherWithHost>
  <button appChildWithHost [key]="'any identifier'">Child 2.1</button>
  <button appChildWithHost [key]="2">Child 2.2</button>
</div>
```